# if variable not in list == False returns empty list

Tags: python, list

I need to make a program that takes a given string of letters and returns all the words within a given list that can be made only with those letters. For this, I used two "for" loops, one for the words in the list and ones for the letters in each word.

Now, so as to obtain only the words that could be made with nothing but the given letters, I used the following method:

```
def combinacion_palabras(lista_palabras,letras):
    palabras_correctas = []
    letras_correctas = []
    for i in letras:
        letras_correctas.append(i)
    for p in lista_palabras:
        for c in p:
            if c not in letras_correctas == False:
                palabras_correctas.append(p)

    return palabras_correctas
```

Where lista_palabras is the list of the given words and letras is the string with the usable letters. I would expect this to return a list with all the words in lista_palabras that are made only of the letters inside the string letras, but instead it returns an empty list. What mistake am I making? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I gave you `c`,`o`,`f`,`e`, could you make the word `coffee`? Does your algorithm account for that?

Comment: You don't need a loop for the letters. Just use `letras` directly...

Comment: I've solved the problem, though I took a different route. Thank you all for your help, regardless. If anyone's curious, the code is as follows:

`def combinacion_palabras(lista_palabras,letras):  
    palabras_correctas = []  
    letras_correctas = list(letras)  
    for p in lista_palabras:  
        k = ''  
        for c in p:  
            if c in letras_correctas:  
                k += c  
                if len(k) == len(p):  
                    palabras_correctas.append(p)  
                 
    return palabras_correctas`

Answer (score 2):

Consider this example:

```
>>> L = ['a', 'b']
>>> 'a' not in L
False
>>> 'a' not in L == False
False
>>> ('a' not in L) == False
True
```

Order of precedence makes the `L == False` go first.

If you want to determine whether an item in the list, just do `if c in letras_correctas:`

Comment: It probably bears mentioning that even with this fix, the algorithm is still going to be wrong (it will return a list with each word repeated as many times as it has valid letters). An ideal fix would probably need an `any` or `all` call with a generator expression inside it, but that may be too advanced for the questioner's homework assignment. Solving it with just simple loops is possible, though not very Pythonic (though it's probably worth learning how, since most other languages require more ugly stuff than Python does).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
def combinacion_palabras(lista_palabras, letras):
    return [palabra for palabra in lista_palabras if set(palabra) <= set(letras) ]

palabras = ['tomo', 'tomas', 'toma', 'tomamos', 'toman', 'mata']

print(combinacion_palabras (palabras, 'tom') )
print(combinacion_palabras (palabras, 'atoms') )
print(combinacion_palabras (palabras, 'tma') )
```

Or rather something like this?

```
def combinacion_palabras(list_palabras, letras):
    return [palabra for palabra in list_palabras if sorted(palabra) == sorted(letras) ]

palabras = ['tomo', 'tomas', 'toma', 'tomamos', 'toman', 'mata']

print(combinacion_palabras (palabras, 'otom') )
print(combinacion_palabras (palabras, 'atoms') )
print(combinacion_palabras (palabras, 'tama') )
```